# Hoc's function can not get the react-redux connect props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to use the connect method from react-redux to pass the props into react hoc high order function.

The wrapper function:

```
export const withInfiniteScroll = (Component) =>
  class WithInfiniteScroll extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false)
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.props.initPage()
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false)
    }
    onScroll = () => {
      (
        (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= (document.body.offsetHeight - 500)
          && this.props.stocks.length
      )
        && this.props.onPaginatedSearch()
    }
    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
```

And the component is wrapped:

```
const StockCard = ({ stocks }) =>
  stocks.errmsg === 'ok' ?
    stocks.data.map (
      (stock, i) =>
        <CardContainer key={i}>
          <p>{stock.cinvcode}</p>
          <p>{stock.cinvname}</p>
        </CardContainer>
      ) : ''
```

Get the hoc function:

```
const StockCardWithInfiniteScroll = withInfiniteScroll(StockCard)
```

The reducer:

```
const initState = {
  ...
  stocks: {
    errcode: '',
    errmsg: '',
    data: []
  }
}

export const PAGE_INIT = 'PAGE_INIT'
export const initPage = () => ({type: PAGE_INIT, payload: 0})

export const STOCK_FETCH = 'STOCK_FETCH'
export const updateStock = (res) => ({type: STOCK_FETCH, payload: res})
export const onPaginated = (searchStock) => {
  return(dispatch) => {
    const searchStockNextPage = {
      ...searchStock,
      pageindex: searchStock.pageindex + 1
    }
    // console.log(searchStockNextPage)
    getStock(searchStockNextPage)
      .then(res => dispatch(updateStock(res)))
      .then(res => console.log(res))
  }
}

const stockReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case PAGE_INIT:
      return {
        ...state,
        searchStock: {...state.searchStock, page: 0}
      }
    case STOCK_FETCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        stocks: state.stocks.data.concat(action.payload.data)
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Last use the connect method to pass the props from redux:

```
export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    stocks: state.stock.stocks
  }),
  {onPaginated, initPage}
)(StockCardWithInfiniteScroll)
```

I can see the feedback stocks props in browser console, but the StockCard can not get it.

Comment: Pls share the code of your reducer

Comment: Fit the reducer code